# Find the point-wise limit function of $ \cos^{2n}(24\pi x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

> Let , $\displaystyle f_n(x)= \cos^{2n}(24\pi x)$. Find the pointwise limit function of the sequence of function $\{f_n(x)\}.$

When , $x$ is irrational then $0<\cos^{2n}(24\pi x)<1$ and so $\cos^{2n}(24\pi x)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Now let , $x=\frac{p}{q}\in \mathbb Q$ where , $gcd(p,q)=1$. Then when $\frac{24p}{q}$ is an integer then $\cos^{2n}(24\pi x)\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$. Now $\frac{24p}{q}$ is an integer when $q|24$ , that is when $q=\{1,2,3,4,6,12,24\}$.

Comment: All those statements seem correct; is there any particular question you would like to ask? If you have a problem with the case where $x$ is rational but $24x$ is not an integer then please say so.

Comment: @ Justpassingby) Yes my problem is that. When $24x$ is not an integer then the limit is $0$. So what is the exact point-wise limit function? How we define it ?

Comment: I think you have already solved it. The limit function is 0 everywhere except at the integer multiples of 1/24, where it is 1.